# Clone Link on Column To Another Column in Table

Tags: jquery, html-table, jquery-clone

I want create `td` and `link image` after `td:nth-child(2)` and clone link `a.link_topic_title`

I have make this script, but the link only clone link on first row

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#preview_active').change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            var url_thread = $('.link_topic_title').attr("href");
            var url_tooltip = "http://example.com" + url_thread
            $(".zebra thead tr th:first-child").attr('colspan', 4);
            $('.zebra tbody tr td:nth-child(2)').after('<td class="span1 icon"><a href="' + url_thread + '"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/must-have/256/Preview-icon.png" height="30px" width="25px" rel="tooltip" data-original-title="' + url_tooltip + '"/></a></td>');
            $('.zebra tbody tr td:nth-child(3) a img[rel=tooltip]').tooltip();
        } else {
            $(".zebra thead tr th:first-child").attr('colspan', 3);
            $('.zebra tbody tr td:nth-child(3)').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/5Vpra/2/

How do I clone list link on column to another column (create td)?

### Update

I have tried using each, I managed to pick up all the links, but not successfully cloned to each td,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#preview_active').change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

            classes = {};
               $('.link_topic_title').each(function() {
               $($(this).attr("href").split(' ')).each(function() { 
               if (this !== '') {
                 classes[this] = this;
                }    
                });
               });

            tds = '';
            $(".zebra thead tr th:first-child").attr('colspan', 4);
            $('.zebra tbody tr td:nth-child(2)').after('<td class="span1 icon"></td>');

            for (class_name in classes) {
             var url_tooltip = "http://example.com" + class_name
             tds += $('.zebra tbody tr td:nth-child(3)').append('<a href="' + class_name + '"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/must-have/256/Preview-icon.png" height="30px" width="25px" rel="tooltip" data-original-title="' + url_tooltip + '"/></a>');
                 $('.zebra tbody tr td:nth-child(3) a img[rel=tooltip]').tooltip();
          };
        } else {
            $(".zebra thead tr th:first-child").attr('colspan', 3);
            $('.zebra tbody tr td:nth-child(3)').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/5Vpra/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solved

I have tried add `index` on `for loop` for identifier of `tr`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#preview_active').change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

            var classes = {};
               $('.link_topic_title').each(function() {
               $($(this).attr("href").split(' ')).each(function() { 
               if (this !== '') {
                 classes[this] = this;
                }    
                });
               });

            tds = '';
            $(".zebra thead tr th:first-child").attr('colspan', 4);
            $('.zebra tbody tr td:nth-child(2)').after('<td class="span1 icon"></td>');
            var i = 0;
            for (class_name in classes) {
             i = i+1;
             var url_tooltip = "http://domain.com" + class_name
             tds +=  $('.zebra tbody tr:nth-child(' + i + ') td:nth-child(3)').append('<a href="' + class_name + '"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/visualpharm/must-have/256/Preview-icon.png" height="30px" width="25px" rel="tooltip" data-original-title="' + url_tooltip + '"/></a>');
                 $('.zebra tbody tr td:nth-child(3) a img[rel=tooltip]').tooltip();
          };
        } else {
            $(".zebra thead tr th:first-child").attr('colspan', 3);
            $('.zebra tbody tr td:nth-child(3)').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

`$('.zebra tbody tr:nth-child(' + i + ') td:nth-child(3)')` result :

`$('.zebra tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3)')`

`$('.zebra tbody tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(3)')`

..

..

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/5Vpra/4/

Answer (score 0):

```
var url_thread = $('.link_topic_title').attr("href");
```

This line is getting attr href from the first .link_topic_title element found. That's why all your created link have the same url. I think you need a for loop in order to know in which row you are every time you are adding a link. But i am not an expert and maybe there is a smoother way to do this.

Comment: I managed to pick up all the links, but not successfully cloned to each td, how can i do that?